# How can I coax an object to a IList<T>?

Tags: .net, generics, reflection

I am using reflection along with linq.Dynamic, and I am having a small problem with creating a query that needs to get `IQueryable<T>` from an `IList<T>` or `ISet<T>` when I currently have an object.

At first I thought I could write a little helper method:

```
object Helper<T>( IList<T> list, string query, param object[] values )
{
... do query and return result.
}
```

Unfortunately the compiler needs to infer the T argument which it cannot do when passed an object.
Is there a simple way to get around this?  I am trying to avoid dynamically invoking this helper function as well.

EDIT:
I have a Domain object that currently as several IList  collections I am trying to query against this class to find the proper object to display on the screen.
Basically I have a screen guid 10 and a xpathish string "FruitBasket/Fruit[Ripe == true]/color"
So I know Fruit is an IList in my reflection code  I inspect the property to find out if it implements IList now I am at the point where i need to query this collection to pick out the Fruit.Ripe == true objects.  For this I need a cast to IQuerable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've only got `object`, how do you expect the compiler to know what `T` should be?

You haven't shown how you're trying to call this method... do *you* know (at compile-time) what the type of `T` should be (even in terms of another type parameter to the calling method)? If not you *will* have to call it dynamically.

Is this `object` *actually* an `IList<T>` for some `T`? What would expect to happen if it implemented `IList<T>` for two different types?

I suggest you take a step back and work out what information is genuinely known at compile time, and what's only known at execution time. Calling a generic method statically *will* require that you know the type arguments at compile time.